# why rpm failed but yum worked for the same downloaded rpm

Tags: centos, yum, rpm

In order to install libpcap-devel offline, I used `yum install -y --downloadonly --downloaddir=. libpcap-devel` and got 2 rpm:
libpcap-1.5.3-12.el7.x86_64.rpm  libpcap-devel-1.5.3-12.el7.x86_64.rpm

Then I used `rpm -ivh libpcap-1.5.3-12.el7.x86_64.rpm`, it says

> Preparing...                          ################################# [100%]
> file /usr/lib64/libpcap.so.1.5.3 from install of libpcap-14:1.5.3-12.el7.x86_64 conflicts with file from package libpcap-14:1.5.3-11.el7.x86_64

I guess it means libpcap.so.1.5.3 has been installed at /usr/lib64 already, and it is 1.5.3-11.el7.x86_64

Then I used `rpm -ivh libpcap-devel-1.5.3-12.el7.x86_64.rpm` it says:

> error: Failed dependencies:
> libpcap = 14:1.5.3-12.el7 is needed by libpcap-devel-14:1.5.3-12.el7.x86_64

Then I used yum localinstall libpcap-devel-1.5.3-12.el7.x86_64.rpm, it succeeded.
My question is, why the same libpcap-devel-12 rpm, rpm command requires libpcap = 14:1.5.3-12.el7, and yum command accept libpcap.so which is 14:1.5.3-11.el7

Comment: it should not accept that. Please double-check what is installed: `rpm -qa | grep libpcap`. To verify the dependencies (whether they are broken or not): `rpm -V libpcap-devel`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`rpm -i` stands form `rpm --install` and is meant for installation of new package.

When you have `package-1.0` installed and you try to `rpm -i package-1.1.rpm`. That it fails. Always. Because of the existing package. You almost always want to use `-U` which means `install or upgrade`.

Yum command `install` will automatically try to downgrade or upgrade to specific version. `localinstall` is just alias to `install` - if the param is a file, it will use the local file.